# ES6 arrow functions returning different values

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I'm new to ES6 and I'm trying to figure out what the difference is between this:

```
const func1 = (x, y) => x * y * 3
```

and this:

```
const func2 = x => y => x * y * 3
```

I have tried running it and I see that the `func1(1,1)` returns `3` and `func2(1)` returns `1`.

1. What are the differences and benefits of one or the other?
2. In what circumstances would you use `func2`?
3. Can someone demonstrate how you would use `func2`?

Comment: *" `func2(1) returns 1` returns 1 "* That cannot be. `func2` returns a function. *"Can someone demonstrate how you would use func2"* `const mult15 = func2(5); console.log(mult15(2))`.

Comment: @FelixKling is func2 using partial application?

Comment: @evolutionxbox: Mmh, I would say "no".  "Partial application" really means that I can only pass some arguments to it, not all of them. However, I am passing all arguments that `func2` expects. But maybe I'm nitpicky. Conceptually yes (I guess) but it's not what actually happens.

Answer (score 6):

`const func1 = (x, y) => x * y * 3` is a standard *arrow function* that translates to this:

```
const func1 = function (x,y) {
    return x * y * 3;
}
```

Whereas,

`const func2 = x => y => x * y * 3` is a [curried function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) where you have a function within another function like this:

```
const func2 = function (x) {
    return function (y) {
       return x * y * 3;
}
```

---

And yeah, as CRice mentioned below, you have to call the parameters spearately with `func2` like this:

```
console.log(func2(a)(b));
```

As opposed to the standard:

```
console.log(func1(a,b));
```

---

> Currying is useful in both practical and theoretical settings. In
>   functional programming languages, and many others, it provides a way
>   of automatically managing how arguments are passed to functions and
>   exceptions. In theoretical computer science, it provides a way to
>   study functions with multiple arguments in simpler theoretical models
>   which provide only one argument.

So `func2` is a function that can be used in situations where for example, you have to return an 'abc' message if certain requirements are met or run a new function with a different logic if the initial requirements are not met.

---

*Quoted Section via - [Wikipedia | Currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)*

Comment: This answered a code review challenge that I bombed :P Awesome to finally know the answer.

Comment: @Doug haha sweet. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Function two is a [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) version of function one. That means that instead of taking a pair of arguments, you pass the first argument in, and it will return you a new function to which you can pass the second argument separately.

Curried functions are useful for creating partially applied functions, among other things. So for your example, you might use those function like so:

```js
const func1 = (x, y) => x * y * 3
const func2 = x => y => x * y * 3

// Two different calling syntaxes, same result:
console.log(func1(2, 3)) // 18
console.log(func2(2)(3)) // 18, note the call chain: (2)(3).

// This is because func2 returns another function.
// You can use that function to partially apply your operation:
const times6 = func2(2);

// Then you can use that elsewhere:
console.log(times6(3)); // 18
console.log(times6(10)); // 60
```